# Finite extension of a characteristic p field is separable if and only if $E=F(E^p)$

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, extension-field, separable-extension

I am trying to show that if $E$ is an extension of a field $F$ with char$(F)$=p, prime, then the extension is separable if and only if $E=F(E^p).$ I have proven that if $\{e_1,\ldots ,e_n\}$ is a basis for $E$ over $F$, then $\{e_1^p,\ldots,e_n^p\}$ is a basis for $F(E^p).$

My approach has been to form the minimal polynomial, $m(X)$, of $e_k$ then show that if it's a polynomial in $p$ then this leads to a contradiction with the irreducibility of min$(e_k^p,F)$. But I am having trouble even getting started.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- $E/F(E^p)=F(e_1,\ldots,e_n)/F(e_1^p,\ldots,e_n^p)$

  If $E\supsetneq F(E^p)$ then $E/F(E^p)$ is purely inseparable so $E/F$ is not separable.
- Conversely if $E/F$ is not separable then let $k\ge 1$ be the least integer such that $\forall a\in E, F(a^{p^k})/F$ is separable.

  $\forall b\in E^p, F(b^{p^{k-1}})/F$ is separable, therefore $\forall b\in F(E^p), F(b^{p^{k-1}})/F$ is separable, so it can't be that $E=F(E^p)$.

Comment: Trying fill in details: $(\Rightarrow)$ We have $F\leq F(E^p) \leq E$ and $E/F$ separable implies $E/F(E^p)$ is separable.  If  $F(E^p)\subsetneq E,$ choose basis element $e_k \in E \setminus F(E^p)$. Then $X^p-e_k^p$ does not factor over $F(E^p)$ and has $e_k$ as a root but is equal to $(X-e_k)^p$ over $E;$ a condradiction. Hence $F(E^p) = E.$

Comment: Filling in details:  ($\Leftarrow$) Such a least integer $k\geq 1$ exists, because $E$ is a finite extension.